# Attach or Detach Element based on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, drop-down-menu

I currently have a form where when a specific option is selected from dropdown 1, then dropdown 2 is revealed-

dropdown 1 -

```
<?php
  echo '<div class="full-divsn"><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 submit-contract-type">';
  echo '<div class="sublabels">Listing Type </div><div class="subins"><select name="contract" id="contracttype" class="form-control" required>';
  $property_contract_type = get_terms('property-contract-type', array(
      'hide_empty' => 0
  ));
  if (!empty($property_contract_type) && !is_wp_error($property_contract_type)) {
      foreach ($property_contract_type as $term) {
           $selected = ($property_contract_type_value == $term->name) ? "selected" : "";
           echo '<option id="' . $term->slug . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $term->name . '</option>';
      }
  } echo "</select>";
  echo '</div></div></div>';
?>
```

dropdown 2 -

```
<div class="full-divsn" id="prop-terms"> <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<div class="sublabels">Terms </div>
<div class="subins">
  <select name="proplength" class="form-control">
    <option selected><?php echo $proplen; ?></option>
    <option value="Month to Month">Month to Month</option>
    <option value="6 Months">6 Months</option>
    <option value="1 Year">1 Year</option>
  </select>
</div></div></div>
```

jQuery -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
$(function() {
  $("#contracttype").change(function() {
    if ($("#for-rent").is(":selected")) {
      $("#prop-terms").show();
    } else {
      $("#prop-terms").hide();
    }
  }).trigger('change');
});
</script>
```

It works fine however, hiding the dropdown still allows the information to be saved to the form so I would like to remove the second dropdown from the form/dom when the correct option is dropdown 1 is not selected but I want it to reappear when that option is selected.

I looked into detach but Im not sure how to apply it to my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `.prop('disabled',...)` like:

<s>`$("#prop-terms").show().prop('disabled',false);`</s>

<s>`$("#prop-terms").hide().prop('disabled',true);`</s>

## UPDATE:

I was unaware that `#prop-terms` is a `<div>`, not being an direct `input`
in that case, you can:

`$("#prop-terms").show().find(':input').prop('disabled',false);`

`$("#prop-terms").hide().find(':input').prop('disabled',true);`

No need to detach/attach, the disabled elements won't be submitted in form request.

Comment: its still being submitted with the form